# remove text from field after submit

Tags: javascript, html, button, send

I have a numeric box with a send button

```
<input id="inputbox" type="number">
<button id="button" type="button" onclick="sendBid()"> Send </button>
```

and after click on button and the information is sent

```
<script>
function sendBid() {
        liveSend(parseInt(inputbox.value));
    }
</script>
```

the number should be removed from the display of the inputbox. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you set the value?

Comment: No, it's empty at the beginning.

Comment: It was a hint to tell you to set the value.....

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function sendBid() {
        liveSend(parseInt(inputbox.value));
        inputbox.value = ""; // This line
    }
</script>
```